# Mapping a common part of the disks

Tags: complex-analysis

Map the common part of the disks $|z|<1$ and $|z-1|<1$ on the inside of the unit circle. Choose the mapping sot hat the two symmetries are preserved.

I don't really know how to approach this??

Any suggestions on how to start constructing such a linear transformation??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the problem statement clear to you?  I'm not sure if you want help with parsing its requirements, or with coming up with a map (function) which fulfills them.

Comment: If you write what related results you know of, then it is easier to write an answer at the right level.

Comment: I am having trouble coming up with the map.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  What sort of mapping is allowed?  Later in the question you refer to a linear transformation, but the region you start with has two corners:  $\frac 12+\frac {\sqrt 3}2i$.  These will need to stay on the circumference, but the angle needs to be straightened out.  Where is the natural place to send them?  The other special points on the region to be mapped are $0$ and $1$ because they are on the other axis of symmetry.  Where should they go?  You still have continuum many points to go, but maybe you can deal with them wholesale now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should identify the points of intersection, which are: $e^{(-\frac {\pi}3)i}$ and $e^{(\frac {\pi}3)i}$. To simplify the answer, I'll call them $a$ and $b$ respectively.
So, we will start with the following mapping: $z_1 =\frac {z-a}{z-b}$. This will map our original region to a wedge from $2\frac {\pi}3$ to $4\frac {\pi}3$.

Our second map will rotate this new region, so that it will map it into a wedge from $0$ to $2\frac {\pi}3$. 
$z_2 = e^{(-\frac {2\pi}3)i} \times z_1$.

Our third map will expand this wedge so that it will be the upper half plane.
$z_3 = (z_2)^{3/2}$.

Now, we will map this last region into the unit circle. $w =\frac {z_3-i}{z_3+i}$.

So, our global map will be: $w = z_3(z_2(z_1(z)))$. Good luck!

Comment: Probably a more intuitive way is to consider the unit circle a region whose boundary consists of the upper circle and the lower circle. Then the similarity between the first transformation and the last becomes obvious. We only need a second in the middle that expands the wedge.

Comment: How do you know where the region will go to after z_1?